# How to properly use 'self' in a protocol extension to avoid having to use protocol stubs?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols

Currently we have a protocol and a protocol extension:

```
protocol Camera: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  func openTheCamera()
}

extension Camera where Self: UIImagePickerController {
    func openTheCamera() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Since the function is already defined in protocol extension, I'm trying call it directly in conforming class:

```
class SomeClass: Camera {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        openTheCamera()
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try and conform the class I get the error:

> Typ UIViewController does not conform to protocol 'Camera'
>   Do you want to add protocol stubs?

The thing is the func is already defined in extension, I don't want to have to add it again to controller. If I add the protocol stubs (openTheCamera(){ }) and leave empty in controller then the function I defined in protocol extension doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procotol condition is wrong. You should use:

```
extension Camera where Self: UIViewController {
```